# Add user to group using Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have installed and configured Ansible on the server for config management purpose.

under **/etc/ansible/hosts** file, I have added [servers] part and mentioned all servers which I need to maintain

I have one **Ubuntu** server in that

In my **test.yml** file I have written this code,

```
---
- hosts: servers
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Add user
    user:
      name: james
      shell: /bin/bash
     groups: wheel
     state: present
    remove: yes
```

Problem is that in Ubuntu there is no **wheel** group present but **sudo** is.

so I want that server to add a user in sudo  group and for others to add to the wheel group

how I can do condition in ansible in that code

Answer (score 4):

You can include variables depending on distribution with [`include_vars` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_vars_module.html).

Ansible saves the value of target system's distribution in `ansible_distribution` fact.

---

Use a variable (`group_for_james`) in your task instead of a string:

```
- name: Add user
  user:
    name: james
    shell: /bin/bash
    groups: "{{ group_for_james }}"
    state: present
    remove: yes
```

Define a default value for user in the play:

```
vars:
  group_for_james: wheel
```

Then create a vars file for Ubuntu (save it for example as `vars/ubuntu.yml`):

```
group_for_james: sudo
```

Add a task (before the `Add user` task) which will overwrite the value if the target is running Ubuntu:

```
- include_vars: vars/ubuntu.yml
  when: ansible_distribution == 'Ubuntu'
```

---

Other patterns for including are also possible, see the third example on the linked doc page.